# XSLT: Conditional replacing using matching

Tags: xslt

I have two XML-files that I currently are merging in a new result XML-file.

First file:

```
<T>
    <T1>AA</T1>
    <T2>1</T2>
</T>    
<T>
    <T1>BB</T1>
    <T2>1</T2>
</T>
<T>
    <T1>AC</T1>
    <T2>1</T2>
</T>
```

Second file:

```
<T>
    <T1>BB</T1>
    <T2>3</T2>
</T>
<T>
    <T1>AB</T1>
    <T2>3</T2>
</T>
```

I want the result to be:

```
<T>
    <T1>AA</T1>
    <T2>1</T2>
</T>    
<T>
    <T1>BB</T1>
    <T2>3</T2>
</T>
<T>
    <T1>AC</T1>
    <T2>1</T2>
</T>
<T>
    <T1>AB</T1>
    <T2>3</T2>
</T>
```

Ie. I want to add the parent nodes `<T>` to the result file if they don't already exist(depending on `<T1>`) in my first file, but replace if they do exist. 
I want the solution to be generic, the solution should work for a "new" second file. 
Can anyone assist, this is what I currently have:

```
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="T">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('./AB.xml')/T/*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

### Edit:

I have two XML-files that I currently are merging in a new result XML-file.
First file:

```
<TT>
<T>
    <T1>AA</T1>
    <T2>1</T2>
</T>    
<T>
    <T1>BB</T1>
    <T2>1</T2>
    <T3>1</T3>
</T>
</TT>
```

Second file:

```
<TT>
<T>
    <T1>AA</T1>
    <T2>3</T2>
    <T3>3</T3>
</T>

<T>
    <T1>BB</T1>
    <T3>3</T3>
</T>
</TT>
```

I want the result to be:

```
<TT>
<T>
    <T1>AA</T1>
    <T2>3</T2>
    <T3>3</T3>
</T>    
<T>
    <T1>BB</T1>
    <T2>1</T2>
    <T3>3</T3>
</T>
</TT>
```

In other words the `<T1>` will be the deciding factor. Answers received so far has been great I just realized that my question actually was more complex than I initially thought.

Comment: Both your inputs are missing a root element. You won't be able to do anything in XSLT unless your input is valid XML.

Comment: I have rolled back your question to its previous version, and **added** your new question to it. Otherwise the previously given answers would make no sense.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two **valid** XML files:

**file1.xml**

```
<input>
    <T>
        <T1>AA</T1>
        <T2>1</T2>
    </T>    
    <T>
        <T1>BB</T1>
        <T2>1</T2>
    </T>
    <T>
        <T1>AC</T1>
        <T2>1</T2>
    </T>
</input>
```

**file2.xml**

```
<input>
    <T>
        <T1>BB</T1>
        <T2>2</T2>
    </T>
    <T>
        <T1>AB</T1>
        <T2>3</T2>
    </T>
</input>
```

when the following stylesheet is applied to file1.xml:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="file2" select="document('file2.xml')" />
<xsl:variable name="localT1s" select="/input/T/T1" />

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <result>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="T"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$file2/input/T[not(T1=$localT1s)]"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="T">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="T1"/>
        <T2>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$file2/input/T[T1=current()/T1]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$file2/input/T[T1=current()/T1]/T2"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="T2"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </T2>   
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
   <T>
      <T1>AA</T1>
      <T2>1</T2>
   </T>
   <T>
      <T1>BB</T1>
      <T2>2</T2>
   </T>
   <T>
      <T1>AC</T1>
      <T2>1</T2>
   </T>
   <T>
      <T1>AB</T1>
      <T2>3</T2>
   </T>
</result>
```

---

### Edit

**In response to your amended question:**
It's not quite clear what do you know about the names of the `<T#>` elements in the input files. If (as I assumed) nothing, then this gets rather complex:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:variable name="file2" select="document('file2.xml')" />

<xsl:template match="/TT">
<xsl:variable name="localT1s" select="T/T1" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="T"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$file2/TT/T[not(T1=$localT1s)]" mode="import"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="T">
<xsl:variable name="elemNames">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <name><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></name>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable> 
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$file2/TT/T[T1=current()/T1]/*[not(name()=exsl:node-set($elemNames)/name)]" mode="import"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>        

<xsl:template match="T/*">
    <xsl:variable name="T1" select="../T1" />
    <xsl:variable name="Tx" select="name()" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$file2/TT/T[T1=$T1]/*[name()=$Tx]">
                <xsl:value-of select="$file2/TT/T[T1=$T1]/*[name()=$Tx]"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="import">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tested the above with these two files:

**file1.xml**

```
<TT>
    <T>
        <T1>A</T1>
        <T2>a2</T2>
    </T>    
    <T>
        <T1>B</T1>
        <T2>b2</T2>
        <T3>b3</T3>
    </T>
</TT>
```

**file2.xml**

```
<TT>
    <T>
        <T1>A</T1>
        <T2>A2</T2>
        <T3>A3</T3>
    </T>
    <T>
        <T1>B</T1>
        <T3>B3</T3>
    </T>
    <T>
        <T1>C</T1>
        <T2>C2</T2>
    </T>
</TT>
```

and received this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TT>
   <T>
      <T1>A</T1>
      <T2>A2</T2>
      <T3>A3</T3>
   </T>
   <T>
      <T1>B</T1>
      <T2>b2</T2>
      <T3>B3</T3>
   </T>
   <T>
      <T1>C</T1>
      <T2>C2</T2>
   </T>
</TT>
```

Comment: This works for the example, but what if the second file looks more like this(with a <T3> in it:

<input>
    <T>
        <T1>BB</T1>
        <T2>2</T2>
        <T3>2</T3>

    </T>
    <T>
        <T1>AB</T1>
        <T2>3</T2>
    </T>
</input>

Or better yet you don't know the total number of other childnodes, but you want to add them all if matching T1 exists?

Comment: @user3485075 Please do not post code in comments. Instead, edit your question and provide a better explanation of your requirement.

Comment: Hi Michael, sorry! Thanks for the feedback! Tried your first answer and it as previously stated worked excellent, but just realized my initial question should have been more complex to begin with. Please see new edit question.

Comment: Ok, this gives me an error message on
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$file2/TT/T[T1=current()/T1]/*[not(name()=exsl:node-set($elemNames)/name)]" mode="import"/>

Stating: Function not in namespaceError in XPath expression, Funtion not in namespace. I can run the code without the later part([not(name()=exsl:node-set($elemNames)/name)]).
Any ideas?
Four matches, indeed a little more complicated, I will need to go through this, I already found some nice tricks in your code.

Comment: @user3485075 Which processor are you using?

Comment: I am using an old XMLSpy version(2005), and I believe it uses a built-in engine for all XSLT debugging. You think I should use something else?

Comment: @user3485075 You need to use a processor that supports the EXSLT exsl:node-set() extension function. I am not aware of a XSLT 1.0 processor that does not support this function, but perhaps it needs to be bound to a different namespace in the stylesheet namespace declarations? You need to see the documentation of your processor for that.

Comment: Hi Michael, you were absolutely right, downloaded latest version of Oxygen and tried with Saxon, worked excellent! I can't thank you enough for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT 2.0 (and then using an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9) you could nicely cross-reference between the two documents:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

<xsl:param name="doc2-url" select="'file2.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="doc2" select="doc($doc2-url)"/>

<xsl:variable name="main-doc" select="/"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="by-T1" match="T" use="T1"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[T]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="T, $doc2//T[not(key('by-T1', T1, $main-doc))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="T[$main-doc is /][key('by-T1', T1, $doc2)]/T2">
  <xsl:copy-of select="key('by-T1', ../T1, $doc2)/T2"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```